# Linking to list of blog posts with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I've made my front page a static page with wordpress. I would still like to be able to link to a listing of blog posts. How is this done?

Comment: list of post means? title only or the full post?

Comment: the title and the post i guess the same way the front page does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new page template file called page-home.php
best way to do this is copy and paste the code from index.php into your new page...
inside this page create a new template call..

```
<?php
/**
 Template Name: home
 */
?>
```

inside this page paste your index.php code..

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content('<p>Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p>Pages: ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

this will display your home page as usual, then you have to create a new call to the wordpress database to display your latest posts from which ever categories you want or show all posts from all categories..

```
<?php

//The Query
query_posts('posts_per_page=5&cat=YOUR_CATEGORY_HERE');

//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 ..
endwhile; else:
 ..
endif;

//Reset Query
wp_reset_query();    
?>
```

this will then loop through the posts and display your latest posts..

have a check through the [wordpress query posts codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: Cheers Marty. But if I then navigate to say page-home.php I get a 404 error :| I guess I need to mess around with the .htaccess file